# How can I add percentages in this combo Chart with Google Chart and Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, google-visualization

Hi I am using Vuejs and I am using google chart I am trying to do a combo Chart that it includes colums and average line, the thing is that the average line must be in percentage and it is taking the same scale of the column and it does not work to me

I am doing this:

```
0: ["Periodo", "2022-05", "2019-05", "Average"]
1: ["MEDS MAIPU", 4295881, 4555755, -6]
2: ["TOTTUS VICUÑA MACKENNA", 1420337, 861260, 65]
3: ["UNIV AUTONOMA", 3106091, 3952437, -21]
4: ["CLINICA AUTONOMA", 0, 543637, -100]
5: ["STA ISABEL VICUÑA MACKENNA", 505589, 737892, -31]
6: ["LIDER GRAN AVENIDA", 1120712, 0, 0]
```

How you can see in this array the average has a very small scale about if you compare with the periods and it is pbecause they are in percentage the thing is that if I add them like that, they assume in the same scale of the period and they do not display because that value is too small so I wonder how can I display them in a combo Chart I mean that they do not take the same scale of the periods?

My vuejs code is this:

```
import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts/legacy'

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    GChart
  },
  created() {
   this.getSaleReport();
  },
  methods: {
    getSaleReport() {
      this.loading = true; //the loading begin
      axios.get('/api/sale/chart?api_token='+App.apiToken)
      .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    this.data = response.data;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    this.loading = false;
  });
  }
 },
 data() {
    return {
    posts: [],
    data: [],
    options: {
    title: 'Informe de Ventas',
    vAxis: { title: 'Monto' },
    hAxis: { title: 'Periodo' },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
    width: '100%',
    height: 600,
  }
}
}
}
```